# Is it possible to change the Proxy in a running WebDriver-Instance?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im currently using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.Chromedriver (C#) to test Websites.
Is there a way to change to Proxy in a running WebDriver-Instance "on the fly"?
I know I could quit the session and start a new one, but it costs performance, so I would like to reuse the existing session.
Is it possible? Maybe with any workarounds?
Changing the local Proxy-Settings from OS is not an option.
Thanks in advance.